# vb.net | How to get empty subdirectories in a specified path ? using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, directory, directoryinfo, getdirectories

My directory structure is like below.

- dir1 > subdir1_1 >((subdir1_1_1 >subdir1_1_1_1),subdir1_1_2)
- dir2

  tow main directories and subdir1_1 have 2 sub-directories (subdir1_1_1 ,subdir1_1_2) and subdir1_1_1 have sub-directory "subdir1_1_1_1"

Ok

Now I have this code

---

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim BaseFolder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Me.TextBox1.Text)

        For Each f As IO.DirectoryInfo In BaseFolder.GetDirectories()
            AddContents(f)
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub AddContents(ByVal BaseFolder As IO.DirectoryInfo)


        For Each subF As IO.DirectoryInfo In BaseFolder.GetDirectories()


            ListBox1.Items.Add(BaseFolder.FullName)

            AddContents(subF)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

and my textbox1.text= "C:\test"

and the result doesn't have  subdir1_1_1_1  and subdir1_1_2 . why ??

where the problem?? why I can't get the empty folder ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SydBe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim BaseFolder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    AddContents(BaseFolder)
End Sub

Sub AddContents(ByVal BaseFolder As IO.DirectoryInfo)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(BaseFolder.FullName)
    For Each subF As IO.DirectoryInfo In BaseFolder.GetDirectories()
        AddContents(subF)
    Next
End Sub
```